# 2010 USAMO #5:Prove that if $\frac{1}{p}-2S_q = \frac{m}{n}$ for integers $m$ and $n$, then $m - n$ is divisible by $p$.

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, contest-math

Let $q = \frac{3p-5}{2}$ where $p$ is an odd prime, and let $S_q = \frac{1}{2\cdot 3 \cdot 4} + \frac{1}{5\cdot 6 \cdot 7} + \cdots + \frac{1}{q(q+1)(q+2)}
 $

Prove that if $\frac{1}{p}-2S_q = \frac{m}{n}$ for coprime integers $m$ and $n$, then $m - n$ is divisible by $p$.

My Progress till now: $$2S_q = 2\sum_{x=1}^{\frac{q+1}{3}} \frac{1}{(3x-1)(3x)(3x+1)} = \sum_{x=1}^{\frac{p-1}{2}} \left[\frac{1}{3x(3x-1)}-\frac{1}{3x(3x+1)}\right]\\
=\sum_{x=1}^{\frac{p-1}{2}} \left[ \frac{1}{3x-1} - \frac{2}{3x} +\frac{1}{3x+1}\right]\\
=\sum_{x=1}^{\frac{p-1}{2}}\left[ \frac{1}{3x-1} + \frac{1}{3x} +\frac{1}{3x+1}\right] - \sum_{x=1}^{\frac{p-1}{2}} \frac{1}{x} $$

With the help of @user10354138 , I have got $\frac{1}{p} - 2S_q = \frac{1}{p} + \frac{1}{1} - \sum_{k=\frac{p+1}{2}}^{\frac{3p-1}{2}}\frac{1}{k} = \frac{m}{n}$

But then I am stuck.

Please give me some hints rather than a solution.
Thanks in advance.

PS: I didn't post it in AOPS, because there we don't get any guidance.

Comment: It would be nice if you join some chat rooms which are mainly developed for problem solving,this room can be helpful https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/77161/basic-mathematics,, this one down is a little higher level for a high schooler but anyway explore it,https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/36/mathematics

Comment: I am sorry , I am new to MSE, what is a chat room ?

Comment: People interact there, about any topic they find interesting, i am sorry i cannot introduce you to others there, i am currently suspended from chatting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**(Original) Hint**: You are almost there with the simplification.  Note that you are summing over $\frac1n$ from $n=2$ to $\frac{3p-1}2$ in the first.  So
$$
2S_q+1=\sum_{n=(p+1)/2}^{(3p-1)/2}\frac1n
$$
If you tweak the RHS slightly, you would be summing over $\frac1n$ as $n$ runs through representative of each of the nonzero residue classes mod $p$.  So ...

---

**Addendum (2020-07-29)**: As discussed in the comments,
\begin{align*}
\frac1p-2S_q-1&=-\left(\sum_{n=(p+1)/2}^{p-1}\frac1n+\sum_{n=p+1}^{p+(p-1)/2}\frac1n\right)\\
&=-\sum_{i=1}^{(p-1)/2}\left(\frac1{p-i}+\frac1{p+i}\right)
\end{align*}
and now
$$
\frac1{p-i}+\frac1{p+i}=\frac{p}{(p-i)(p+i)}
$$
so the numerators are divisible by $p$ and the denominators are not.  So putting everything over a common denominator, we see
$$
\frac{m-n}{n}=-\sum_{i=1}^{(p-1)/2}\frac{p}{(p-i)(p+i)}=\frac{p\times \text{some integer}}{\text{some integer not divisible by }p}.
$$
That is, every representation of $\frac{m-n}{n}$ must have more factors of $p$ in the numerator than in the denominator, hence $m-n$ is divisible by $p$.

Comment: aren't we summing 1/n from n=2 to 3(p-1)/2 +1 ?

Comment: Oops, yes it should be $(3p-1)/2$, corrected.

Comment: So we have ,$\frac{1}{p} - 2S_q = \frac{1}{p} + \frac{1}{1} - \sum_{k=\frac{p+1}{2}}^{\frac{3p-1}{2}}\frac{1}{k} = \frac{m}{n}$

Comment: also can you explain this line , " you would be summing over 1/ as  runs through representative of each of the nonzero residue classes mod "

Comment: As $k$ runs through $(p+1)/2$ to $(3p-1)/2$ it is $p$ consecutive numbers you are taking reciprocal of.  If you cancel out the $1/p$ then those $k$s leave remainders $1,2,\dots,p-1$ when divided by $p$, in some order.

Comment: In fact you can see you are summing $(p-1)/2$ reciprocals from $k=(p+1)/2$ to $p-1$, then another $(p-1)/2$ reciprocals from $k=p+1$ to $(3p-1)/2$.  What would be a nice thing to do in this situation?

Comment: yes, I understood what you wrote but we need to write $\frac{1}{p} - 2S_q=m/n$

Comment: When we consider modulo p then we have $\sum_{i=1}^{p-1} i^{-1} = \sum_{i=1}^{p-1} i$

Comment: You are overthinking it a little.  We have $$\frac1p-2S_q=1-\left(\sum_{k=(p+1)/2}^{p-1}\frac1k+\sum_{k=p+1}^{(3p-1)/2}\frac1k\right).$$Can you do something to the bracketed two sums to make it just one sum (from $i=1$ to $(p-1)/2$)?

Comment: we can subtract 1/p to both the sides

Comment: Can you post your solution? I am probably missing some idea ?

Comment: Can you see it can be written as $$\frac1p-2S_q=1-\left(\sum_{i=1}^{(p-1)/2}\frac1{p-i}+\sum_{i=1}^{(p-1)/2}\frac1{p+i}\right)?$$  What can you do to make the $(\dots)$ into a single sum from $i=1$ to $(p-1)/2$?

Comment: I posted the solution, can you once proof read it ?

Comment: also, I am really sorry that I removed the green tick thing from your hint because technically your answer was a hint which really helped a lot . I am really grateful to your hint .

Answer (score 0):

With the help of @user10354138 's hints, I think I got the solution.I will be grateful if someone proof reads it.

Note that $$2S_q = 2\sum_{x=1}^{\frac{q+1}{3}} \frac{1}{(3x-1)(3x)(3x+1)} = \sum_{x=1}^{\frac{p-1}{2}} \left[\frac{1}{3x(3x-1)}-\frac{1}{3x(3x+1)}\right]\\
=\sum_{x=1}^{\frac{p-1}{2}} \left[ \frac{1}{3x-1} - \frac{2}{3x} +\frac{1}{3x+1}\right]\\
=\sum_{x=1}^{\frac{p-1}{2}}\left[ \frac{1}{3x-1} + \frac{1}{3x} +\frac{1}{3x+1}\right] - \sum_{x=1}^{\frac{p-1}{2}} \frac{1}{x}$$ .

Proceeding further we get that,$$\frac{1}{p} - 2S_q = \frac{1}{p} + \frac{1}{1} - \sum_{k=\frac{p+1}{2}}^{\frac{3p-1}{2}}\frac{1}{k} = \frac{m}{n}$$

or we get that $$- 2S_q = \frac{1}{1} - \sum_{k=\frac{p+1}{2}}^{\frac{3p-1}{2}}\frac{1}{k} = \frac{m}{n}-\frac{1}{p}$$

Now, note that $$\sum_{k=\frac{p+1}{2}}^{\frac{3p-1}{2}}\frac{1}{k}\equiv \sum_{k=1}^{p-1}\frac1k \equiv \sum_{k=1}^{p-1}k \equiv 0$$ mod $p$

So we get that $$\frac{m}{n}\equiv 1$$ mod $p$ .

Hence we have $$1-\frac{m}{n}\equiv 0$$ mod p $$\implies m-n \equiv 0 $$ mod  $p$.

And we are done!

Comment: How did you get  $\sum_{k=\frac{p+1}{2}}^{\frac{3p-1}{2}}\frac{1}{k}\equiv \sum_{k=1}^{p-1}\frac1k $ mod p ?
I understood the rest part though..

Comment: @Raheel , Note that $\sum_{k=\frac{p+1}{2}}^{\frac{3p-1}{2}}\frac{1}{k}$ is nothing but p consecutive integers in their multiplicative inverse  modulo p .

Comment: oh..I see, thanks

Comment: You need to be careful about what you mean by taking a fraction in $\mathbb{Q}$ modulo $p$.